# Cannot ping localhost

Tags: networking, ntp, timekeeping

While setting up an ntp client/server, I found a weird error where the client cannot check it's own time.

I have traced this back to the fact that all of these commands time out:

```
ping localhost
ping 127.0.0.1
ping 127.0.1.1
ping hostname
ping 192.168.0.x
```

My hostname is set in /etc/hostname and is the same as my /etc/hosts file, which looks like this:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0     ip6-localnet
ff00::0     ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1     ip6-allnodes
ff02::2     ip6-allrouters

127.0.1.1   hostname
```

I can't see any problems here.... The hostname is also unique for the network which is unmanaged and uses static IPs instead of dhcp.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What does "ip addr" return in the command line?

Answer (score 2):

I found the issue - in /etc/network/interfaces I had commented out the line:

```
iface lo inet loopback
```

I found it by running ifconfig and seeing if there was the loopback interface, which there wasn't